# Monitor tcpflow output with Java?

Tags: java, tcpdump

How can I monitor tcpflow output with Java?
I've tried the following but it doesn't work with the tcp flow **-c** arg.

```
Process process;

try {
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tcpflow -c");
    InputStreamReader ir = new 
    InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
    LineNumberReader input = new LineNumberReader(ir);
    String line;
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Output: " + line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How come the output of tcpflow isnt read? However if I exec the **tcpflow -h** the output is read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a work around by tailing a log file from tcpflow.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File log = new File("packets.log");
    PacketListener listener = new PacketListener();
    Tailer tailer = Tailer.create(log, listener, 2500);
    tailer.run();
}
```

And the class that trails it.

```
public class PacketListener extends TailerListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void handle(String line) {
        System.out.println("Inbound: " + line);
    }

}
```